# How to enter the value of HTML Input Field in MVC Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-pages

I have a HTML Form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("WorksCompletedToday", "Report", new { DateTimes = "09/10/2020" }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Search by Date:</label>
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="toDate">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        }
```

While submitting this form the value of DateTimes is "09/10/2020" be default. How can I send the value that I enter in the input tag of `id=toDate`?

Comment: Form fields need a `name` attribute in the HTML, otherwise the browser will not submit them. So probably `name="DateTimes` in your case. And remove the default from the BeginForm command. But in MVC, if you want to bind a field to your model, you should generally use the Html.EditorFor() command to generate the correct HTML for you automatically. I wonder if you need to study some tutorials a bit more closely, because this kind of thing should be explained in beginners' materials.

Comment: Also `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` is not necessary unless the form will be used to upload files. It shouldn't do any harm, but it's not needed.